# Can you sort a DataGridView on a manually added DataGridViewComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that is filled from a DataTable tied to a binding source. I hide a column through the DataTable’s ColumnMapping

```
dataTable.Columns[“ZoneId“].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden;
```

I have tied the DataGridView's `DataBindingComplete` event to a method that iterates through the rows looking at the DataBound ZoneId column and then setting the ComboBox for the row to match the ZoneId.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.Rows.Count - 1; i++) {  //Count-1 to ignore the editing row
  // This is the DataGridView row, a subset of the backing data plus the combo and button cells
  DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView.Rows[i];
  // This is the full backing data for the row
  DataRowView dataRow = (DataRowView)row.DataBoundItem;
  if (dataRow != null) {
    // Find cell with comboBox by name 
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = DataGridViewComboBoxCell)row.Cells["ZoneIdComboBox"];
    if (cell != null) {
      Id = (string)dataRow["ZoneId"];
      cell.Value = Id;
    }
  }
}
```

The Value of the ComboBox is equal to the hidden column value (ID) stored in the table. The Text portion is the human readable description of that value. These are defined by a separate table in the database. Also the two tables have a relationship so the ZoneId in my main table must mach an Id in my ComboBox table.

I can click the header of any of the regularly bound columns and sort the table. I would like to be able to click the ComboBox column and sort on the Text entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real solution is to set `AutoGenerateColumns = false`. Then create all of the columns manually. I do this when the `DataGridView` is initially loaded. After that I don't have to do it again.

```
private DataGridViewComboBoxColumn MakeDataGridViewComboBoxColumn(string fieldName, string headerText, DataGridViewColumnSortMode sortMode, bool readOnly)
{
  DataGridViewComboBoxColumn result = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
  result.Name = fieldName;
  result.DataPropertyName = fieldName;
  result.HeaderText = headerText;
  result.SortMode = sortMode;
  result.ReadOnly = readOnly;
  return result;
}
```

Afterwards I populate the ComboBox column with a separate DataSource either a list or datatable.

```
private void QueueBindZoneColumn()
{
  // The available ZoneId list may have been edited, so get a fresh copy
  DataGridViewComboBoxColumn c = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dgv1.Columns["ZoneId"];
  if (c != null) {
    c.ValueType = typeof(string);
    List<Data.Zone> ZoneList;
    if (Data.LoadZoneId.Load(txtConnectionString.Text, out ZoneList)) {
      c.DataSource = ZoneList;
      c.DisplayMember = "ZoneDescription";    //List class member name to display as descriptions
      c.ValueMember = Data.FieldNameHandling.Id;  //List class member name to use as the stored value
    }
  }
}
```

When the DataGridView BindingSource is assigned, the ComboBox values are set because the table's fieldName matches the ComboBox's `DataPropertyName`.

The great thing is this means I do not have to manually deal with assigning the data from a ComboBox change to the backing store data like I was.

It also handles the changing of data, I now longer have to verify the ComboBoxes.

With the data loaded I can sort the rows based on the values in the ComboBox. I could probably override the Sort method to sort on the Text information.